# Capturing output works on rails console but not on Sidekiq job

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rather simple python script that I call from a Sidekiq job. Capturing the variable works on the Rails console but not in the Sidekiq job. I instead got `sh: 145.152: command not found`. Any clue?

This is how I call it:

```
    @file.source_file.open do |file|
      Sidekiq.logger.info("File path: #{file.path}")
      result = %x(`python audio_length.py #{file.path}`)
      Sidekiq.logger.info("Result: #{result}")
    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use backticks: `` `command` `` or backtick [literal](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-25x-3A+Backtick+Literals) `%x(command)`. When you do both you're capturing and running captured result as a command again, I assume that's not what you want.

```rb
>> `echo "hi"`
=> "hi\n"

>> %x(echo "hi")
=> "hi\n"

>> %x(`echo "hi"`)
sh: 1: hi: not found
=> ""
```